# Myhill-Nerode on a language of all binary strings whose last two symbols are the same

Tags: solution-verification, automata, regular-language

This is a question from a MCQ competitive exam: **Let $L$ be the set of all binary strings whose last two symbols are the same. What are the number of states in the minimum state deterministic finite-state automaton accepting $L$?**

**The answer is 5** according to the solution key though no method is specified.

My attempt at solving is to use the Myhill-Nerode theorem i.e. by partitioning the language into equivalence classes. My understanding is that the number of classes is the number of states needed in the DFA.

I can immediately think of three equivalence classes:

- non-empty strings ending at $0$
- non-empty strings ending at $1$
- empty strings

I believe this covers all the possible classes. If so, then the number of states in the DFA should only be 3. Try as I might I could not construct this DFA. Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: Hint: Are $0$ and $00$ in the same equivalence class?

Comment: Four combinations 00, 01, 10, and 11.

Comment: @leoli1, so I should be thinking: are there any strings $z \in \Sigma^*$ that can be concatenated to $0$ and $00$ such that one would be accepted and one would be _not_... I can only think of manually checking say $0$ (both are accepted), $1$ (both are not accepted), $01$ (both not accepted), $11$ (both accepted). Is there a systematic way to do this?

Comment: Ugh got it, the empty string is part of the language too... $\epsilon \in Z^*$ should be one of the checks and that shows $0$ and $00$ are part of different classes. Similar argument for $1$ and $11$ too?

Comment: Yes, similar argument.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow $\epsilon \in \Sigma^*$ has still not sunk in...